# How to debug c++ code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk

I use Android Studio 1.5.1 and Windows 7. I installed LLDB, but when I put a breakpoint in my native code, nothing happens. It may be necessary to set some settings in native debugger to make it work?

[image]

I can't believe I can't don't allow to debug my native code in such a powerful tool like Android Studio.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713274/debug-native-code-in-android-studio) help?

Comment: No, it didn't help. I already have the debugger with same configuration by default (see screenshot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get NDK debugging to work in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413593/how-to-get-ndk-debugging-to-work-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

About same question has been asked at the end of the link, you can check the answer.
[How to get NDK debugging to work in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413593/how-to-get-ndk-debugging-to-work-in-android-studio)