# Android APK: Debugging an APK with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am debugging an APK with Android Studio

I'm at MainActivity - I have decompiled the APK to give me the .java files

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final native boolean checkPassword(String str);

/* access modifiers changed from: protected */
@Override // androidx.activity.ComponentActivity, androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity, androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity, androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.loadLibrary("ferriswheel");
}

public final void checkHandler(View view) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(view, "view");
    View findViewById = findViewById(R.id.password_input);
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(findViewById, "findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password_input)");
    if (checkPassword(((EditText) findViewById).getText().toString())) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ferriswheel.class));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect!", 1).show();
    }
}
```

}

I'm not sure what's happening here - the `checkPassword` part - what is it checking against? If I set a breakpoint, it doesn't seem to get hit when I run the app

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: `native boolean checkPassword(String str)` is a native method called through JNI.

Comment: are you sure you are running with debug app or directly attaching debugger ? please check this also https://stackoverflow.com/q/30713274/9909365

Comment: Do you have some more context to this? Debugging an APK isn't straightforward if you don't have access to the real source code. You need to be able to recompile it if you want to do it like that which also isn't straightforward since the decompiler may not be able to make sense of all of the code. Are you trying to reverse engineer something?